# Python - Abstract class subclassing

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm trying to find the best for users of my python library to implement an abstract class I wrote.
Namely, my abstract class define an API to access specific values stored in a database, but I would like to let the user choose how to store it (simple text file, json, sqlite, etc.)

My problem is, how should I retrieve the class the user create and use it in my library ?

This is the solution I came up with, but I don't find it very graceful and wonder if there is a more pythonic way.

In my library:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Database(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def get(self, index):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def insert(self, data):
        pass

def get_database():
    """call this anywhere I need a concrete database class"""
    return Database.__subclasses__()[-1]
```

In the user code

```
class SqliteDatabase(Database):

    def get(self, index):
        # sqlite SELECT and such
        return data

    def insert(self, data):
        # sqlite INSERT INTO
        # return data with index provided
        return data
```

Of course, I will return a better error than `IndexError` if there is no subclass defined, but you get the idea.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?  Where is the problem?

Comment: Why are you retrieving the class like that? Shouldn't the client pass in an instance of their subclass?

Comment: @James There is no problem per se, cause everything work in the current state. I just want to know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: @Blorgbeard They could, but I'd rather not have dependency injection if it's avoidable. A simple subclassing should be enough, and my library would do the legwork

Comment: I wouldn't call myself fluent in python, but I would consider this API quite surprising. I'd expect at least to pass the *class* to the library rather than have it detect it. What if I have a couple of different implementations for different scenarios?

Comment: You are probably right. I just thought that by a mere subclassing, the API would be more frictionless

Answer (score 1):

I finally settled for something else, as Blorgbeard suggested

```
_databases = {}

def register(dbname="default"):
    def wrapper(klass):
        _databases[dbname] = klass
        return klass
    return wrapper

def get_db(name="default"):
    return _databases[name]
```

And the user only needs to declare

```
@register()
class SqliteDatabase:

    def __get__(self, index):
        # retrieve data
        if data is None:
            raise KeyError(index)
        return data
```

This way, anybody can declare as many as databases as they want.
If you have improvements over this version, I'll gladly take them.